# QGIS server installation: Do I need to create a qgis user?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ubuntu, qgis-server

I am following the instructions in the [official docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html) to install QGIS Server (3.8) on my Ubuntu server (18.04).

Throughout the docs, a `/home/qgis/` folder is mentioned.

[**12.1.3. Follow Along: HTTP Server Configuration**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html#fa-http-server-configuration)

(*qgis.demo.conf*)

> # default QGIS project   SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE
>
> **/home/qgis**/projects/world.qgs
>
> # QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH must lead to a directory writeable by the
>   Server's FCGI process user   FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH
>   "**/home/qgis**/qgisserverdb/"   FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_PASSWORD_FILE
>   "**/home/qgis**/qgisserverdb/qgis-auth.db"
>
> # See
>   https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#pg-service-file
>   SetEnv PGSERVICEFILE /home/qgis/.pg_service.conf   FcgidInitialEnv
>   PGPASSFILE "/home/qgis/.pgpass"
>
> # default QGIS project   SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE
>   **/home/qgis**/projects/world.qgs

and then again (same paragraph)

> mkdir **/home/qgis**/qgisserverdb chown www-data:www-data
>   **/home/qgis**/qgisserverdb

However, I don't have a `qgis` user in my system nor the installation has created one for me.

So the question is:

Do I need to create a `qgis` user or should I change all the references to `/home/qgis` to `/home/myuser`?

I cannot seem to find anything useful about this not even in the [**Advanced configuration**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/config.html) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would say **no**, like you said **you should simply change the paths to match yours**.

My .conf file is quite poor compared to the one provided by the tutorial. What the tutorial .conf file does, it defines logging variables and other configurations, but the most imporant thing is handling your .cgi requests. This virtual host will now pretend to receive requests on behalf of localhost at qgis.demo.